# What is the difference between source code and DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, dom, uiwebview

- In my app I want to process Google Translate definitions, like definition for the word "song"

[image]

- When I check returned http message, it does NOT contain the "short poem"
  expression.

[image]

- But in DOM tree view in Safari I can see the "short poem" info.

[image]

- This is because after loading page some JavaScript code do some
  magic? How would you get `DOM tree` in an iOS app? `UIWebView` can do
  such a magic?

Comment: If you want to access Translate programmatically, you should use the [API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/), not their html frontend (which is both technically cumbersome and a violation of their TOS).

Comment: @georg it's paid service, I assume he's trying to workaround that

Comment: Google Translate API cost money even if it is cheap, but the real downside that the english definition / synonyms are not available with API, and I need that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The notions between a page's source and a page's DOM are similar, but different. The source is the raw HTML that is unadulterated by any client-side scripts. It is the direct response of the HTTP request to the server. The DOM, on the other hand, is the same HTML structure that has been modified by JavaScript.

Source Code reads the page's HTML as if you opened it in a text editor. The source code reflects your HTML structure before any JavaScript is loaded. While the contents can’t be edited, it’s useful to see the HTML the browser receives from the server.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/ResourcesandtheDOM/ResourcesandtheDOM.html

Try to read about API, I think there are API's for translate and stuff

Comment: The DOM is not necessarily altered by JavaScript. It is the object tree that was parsed from the raw HTML, that then is *available to scripts to manipulate*.