# Javascript/jquery change text into tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to send message with js on twitch.tv. 
For this i can try change textarea in chatbox.

```
<textarea class="tw-textarea tw-textarea--no-resize " placeholder="Send message" data-a-target="chat-input" data-test-selector="chat-input" style="padding-right: 6rem;"></textarea>
```

With this code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('tw-textarea tw-textarea--no-resize ')[0].value=1;
```

Text changing on page (visual), but not changing in source code, how to fix it?

Comment: Try using only 1 of the classes

Comment: What do you mean "Source code does not change"? I feel you are sitting on a big misconception.

Answer (score 1):

`.getElementsByClassName` only allows one class to select by, if you want to use multiple, you would have to use `.querySelector()` for the first appereance or `.querySelectorAll()` for all appereances and use a valid css selector as parameter.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.tw-textarea.tw-textarea--no-resize ')[0].value = 1;
```

```html
<textarea class="tw-textarea tw-textarea--no-resize " placeholder="Send message" data-a-target="chat-input" data-test-selector="chat-input" style="padding-right: 6rem;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Try this on twitch.tv textarea changing only visual. Source code of page do not changed.

Comment: code in browser this: <textarea class="tw-textarea tw-textarea--no-resize " placeholder="Send message" data-a-target="chat-input" data-test-selector="chat-input" style="padding-right: 6rem;"></textarea>

Comment: But do you mean the raw HTML code you see by going to view page source or the DOM code you see with page inspector in your dev tools? (they're [not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29273391/what-is-the-difference-between-source-code-and-dom))

Comment: Then use `element.setAtrribute("value", 1)` instead of `element.value = 1`. Also, I suggest giving your textarea a unique id so you can select it with `document.getElementById(id)` instead of `document.getElementsByClassname(classList)[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this, you may try using `.querySelector`, which gives only one element:

```
document.querySelector('.tw-textarea.tw-textarea--no-resize').value=1;
```

**Snippet:**

```js
document.querySelector('.tw-textarea.tw-textarea--no-resize').value=1;
```

```html
<textarea class="tw-textarea tw-textarea--no-resize " placeholder="Send message" data-a-target="chat-input" data-test-selector="chat-input" style="padding-right: 6rem;"></textarea>
```

This will work if the classes are in any order and also gives **only one element**.

> *Text changing on page (visual), but not changing in source code, how to fix it?*

Do you mean to change in the view source or the file itself? No not possible. This will be just run time. And if this is not executing when the page starts, it doesn't permanently get saved into the file system as well. Yes, it's **just visual**. HTML **cannot** write to files.

Comment: Try this on twitch.tv textarea changing only visual. Source code of page do not changed.

Comment: But if I tape manual text in textarea tag changing, why its no possible??

Comment: @deathnoob HTML cannot be used to write to files / change the source code. When you do in other site which you mentioned, they use a server side programming language to capture your input and change it.

Comment: @deathnoob I understand what you wanted to do. That works if you do like: `document.querySelector('.tw-textarea.tw-textarea--no-resize').innerHTML = 1;`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I wanted send message on the site twitch.tv. All you need is to enter the text in the chatbox and click the Chat button. But it doesn't work...

Comment: Click the chat button (works fine) document.getElementsByClassName('chat-input__buttons-container tw-flex tw-justify-content-between tw-mg-t-1')[0].getElementsByClassName('tw-button')[0].click();

Comment: @deathnoob I am not sure all browsers happily support delegating the click event that way. Some browsers block it. Check the console for any errors regarding that. Every time you click on it will throw an error in the console.

Comment: Click works if I tape text manual. But if I put it with JS result is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
document.getElementsByClassName('tw-textarea tw-textarea--no-resize ')[0].innerText = "1";
```

instead of

```
document.getElementsByClassName('tw-textarea tw-textarea--no-resize ')[0].value=1;
```

Also, I suggest giving your textarea a unique id like this:

```
<textarea id="message"></textarea>
```

so you can simply select it with `document.getElementById("message")` or `document.querySelector("#message")` 
instead of using `document.getElementsByClassname(classList)[0]`.

Comment: Not attribute value! text into tag! This: <textarea id="message">TEXT</textarea>

Comment: @deathnoob Oh, in that case just use `element.innerText = 1`