# Downloaded HTML does not contain elements displayed in web browser

Tags: c#, html

I used the following code to download a page's HTML as text:

```
        string requestUri = "some site";
        string html;

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            html = client.DownloadString(requestUri);
        }

        File.WriteAllText("C:\\html.txt", html);
```

However the resulting text file does not contain any of the elements that my web browser displays. I searched for any of a series of keywords but none appear in the html, while they appear in my browser and browser's "inspect element" thingy.

As far as I know the downloaded HTML should contain EVERYTHING that is displayed in the browser and more.

**Why is the downloaded HTML text missing virtually everything that is displayed in the browser?**

Comment: Please tag the language you're using.

Comment: You might want to read this: [What is the difference between source code and DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29273391/what-is-the-difference-between-source-code-and-dom)

Comment: @Utkanos, I thought it'd be more of a general coding question, but OK.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, yes, it does.

Comment: @Utkanos, thanks that answered my question.

Comment: Use a WebBrowser **class** to get and render the html. Then you can parse it using the native HtmlDocument methods (GetElemetById, GetElementsByTagName etc.) or pass the document `html` to HtmlAgilityPack if you prefer this parser instead.

Comment: Also look into [headless browsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser). Ultimately if you want to get the resultant DOM, not the server-sent source code, you'll need something that can interpret JavaScript as that's the fundamental actor between DOM and source code.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest [HTMLAgility](https://html-agility-pack.net/) pack for this:

With HtmlAgility, you can simply do this:

```
string webUrl = "http://microsoft.com";

var page = new HtmlWeb();
var document = page.Load(url);
page.Get(url, "/");
document.Save("test.html");
```

Comment: While I thank you for your assistance, as this will be of use, it does not answer my question, so I cannot mark it as answer.

Comment: Wait, I take my last comment back - the operation "`page.Load`" times out, so I can't verify this actually works.

Comment: After this finally worked - Dammit, this does nothing. From what I see it's the same as my code, but 1000 times slower and requiring a clumsy third party. I wish I could take my vote back, but it's locked, now. :/