# How can i change source code any webpage with chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am trying make a my own **chrome extension**. Yes i did it. But there is a problem with change html dom with javascript. i cant change source code. it works only web page interface.. I need to see my new html tags when i clicked the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can't change "source code", or at least, not like the way you can do so with the DOM.

The view source views the *raw data (in this case, code) sent back from the source* (hence known as "source code").

To view changes, you have to open devtools and go to "elements", or use an extension that views the rendered source, like [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/view-rendered-source/ejgngohbdedoabanmclafpkoogegdpob).

The source code is "static" (by static I mean, not changing even after the webpage is rendered and mutated. Technically, the server can send a different response as it wishes, but for this scenario we'll say it's "static"). It does not change like the DOM does. The source code is rendered by the browser into a webpage, which you can then access the DOM via scripts, or devtools. The source code is just raw data, you can't "change it" like you can with the DOM. Here's a good SO Q/A that shows you the difference between the DOM and the source code: [What is the difference between source code and DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29273391/what-is-the-difference-between-source-code-and-dom)

What you *can* do, though, is mutate the *request* via the `chrome.webRequest`, which I believe allows you to also mutate request responses (basically turning your extension into a proxy).

Read more about `chrome.webRequest` here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/